# microservices deployment on prem

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

We have 3 micro services ( M1, M2, M3 ) and one angular app ( UI ) and planning to deploy it on  on-prem servers. We have two servers.

On both servers we are running instances of all 3 microservice and angular app will be only on one server.

Server 1 -  M1, M2, M3, Spring cloud gateway, Service discovery

Server 2 -  M1, M2, M3, Service discovery

For High Availability, we will be forming cluster of service discovery  on both servers.

In this approach there will be bottleneck  at UI and spring cloud gateway level.   Could anyone suggest the better approach for this deployment. Should we use any load balancer in front of UI and gateway ?

Thanks

Comment: "angular app will be only on one server" seems like a strange choice.  why not have it on both servers?  If you're savvy enough for service discovery you can probably save yourself a lot of hassle just using kubernetes for this stuff so you have a pluggable cloudlike orchestration layer.  Then you'll get service discovery load balancing and other components almost for free (free as in effort of course.  all the software is OSS)

Comment: thanks for quick response.   yes.. thats strange one..  and we can not use kubernetes for some reason.  hence thinking of adding LB in-front of UI and api gateway.. Is this good approach or anything better without kubernetes

Comment: Something like HAProxy would be great.  Set it up on both servers and it can route all your traffic for you.